# Xamarin Android java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to implement java library into xamarin. For that I created a java binding library and referenced dll into my xamarin.android project. Basically JBL generated code looks like as below. as you can see that it has no constructor with 0 parameters.

```
public abstract class SAAgent : Service
{

        [Register(".ctor", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "")]
        protected SAAgent(string p0);
        protected SAAgent(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer);
        [Register(".ctor", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)V", "")]
        protected SAAgent(string p0, Class p1);
```

I implemented a class inheriting this generated SAAgent class.

```
 [Service(Exported = true, Name = "WearCompanion.Droid.ProviderService")]
    public class ProviderService : SAAgent 
    {   

        public ProviderService() : base("ProviderService", SASOCKET_CLASS)
        {

        }
```

when I execute the code, I receive an exception telling that

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException   Message=Unable to instantiate service
>   WearCompanion.Droid.ProviderService:
>   java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   java.lang.Class has no zero
>   argument constructor

so it is expecting me to have 0 argument constructor. There is a sample on Samsung Tizen website and their java sample looks like as below

```
public class ProviderService extends SAAgent {
    private static final String TAG = "HelloAccessory(P)";
    private static final Class<ServiceConnection> SASOCKET_CLASS = ServiceConnection.class;

    public ProviderService() {
        super(TAG, SASOCKET_CLASS);
    }
```

But when I look at the obj folder of my xamarin.android project and find ProviderClass.java file generated. it looks like as below,

```
public class ProviderService
    extends com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAAgent
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer
{


    public ProviderService (java.lang.String p0, java.lang.Class p1)
    {
        super (p0, p1);
        if (getClass () == ProviderService.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("WearCompanion.Droid.ProviderService, WearCompanion.Android", "System.String, mscorlib:Java.Lang.Class, Mono.Android", this, new java.lang.Object[] { p0, p1 });
    }
```

I dont understand how can I make that xamarin produces a java class from c# with 0 constructor? 
Is that a java binding problem?

PS, I have decompiled jar to see SAAgent java implementation and it is the same as C# one. so java binding library did a correct job. I am not sure if I should manually add a parameterless constructor myself?

Comment: According to your code, SAAgent don't have 0 argument constructor, ProviderService class inherit SAAgent , so it should `public ProviderService(string p0, Class p1) : base(p0, p1)`

Comment: @CherryBu thats true. Original Java SAAgent class also doesnt have 0 argument constructor but inherited class has it as it is shown in the 3rd code piece. So error is also for ProviderService having 0 parameters. my c# code is converted by Xamarin.Android into 4th code piece but it should be converted as 3rd one above. this is my problem. maybe it is a bug in xamarin or there is something from c# to java i should handle

Comment: You can add parameter constructor manually, and see if it works.

Comment: @CherryBu it is actually expecting a zero parameter. so i should be able to define in c# as  public ProviderService() but i get build error if i try this because it says base doesnt contain any zero parameter but on runtime it complains otherway around that ProviderService doesnt have zero parameter constructor. Because Xamarin produces java class like in my question. it should produce a class  public ProviderService() {
        super(TAG, SASOCKET_CLASS); like this. there is a difference between these 2 in java obviously but not in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Xamarin actually has in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/limitations#missing-constructors) regarding missing constructor. as explained, it should be used a Export attribute. So if i change my C# class constructor as below. It generates exact java class as expected with zero parameter constructor.

```
 [Export(SuperArgumentsString = "\"ProviderService\", ProviderService_ProviderServiceSocket.class")]
        public ProviderService() : base("ProviderService", SASOCKET_CLASS)
        {

        }
```